# How can I display the Futura font default in OSX 10.10.5 across all browsers?

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I just realized to my horror that not all computers/browsers/OSs have the default Futura font installed. I display it on my website but is thus not viewable for all visitors as this font is not default when using other OS than OSX. What is the best way to overcome this problem and maintain the Futura font?

Comment: Try to find Futura as a webfont.

Comment: It is non-existing I believe and one needs to pay for it. Only alternatives available.

Comment: Not a lot of other options then.

Comment: You are correct. Here are all your [`legal options`](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/futura/licensing.html) if you want to use the original font. The illegal options are either plain using a desktop version of it and any online service to turn it into a webfont or using one of the many alternate fonts which are, for the most part, exact duplicates.

Comment: Could I use this https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack and then put upload the font to my site and then source it. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed my issue in the following way:

1) Went to http://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack to convert OSX Futura.ttc to Futura.ttf

2) Then created Futura.woff and Futura.woff2 files at: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

3) Then added the following code to style.css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Futura';
src:
    local('Futura'),
    url('fonts/Futura.ttc'),
    url('fonts/Futura.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Futura.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

I added the fonts to the fonts/ folder which is in the same directory as my style.css.